# Conventions and native support for defining private functions inside a module

Tags: powershell

PowerShell modules make it possible to have private "methods", but I can't find any conventions or support for defining them as such. For larger scripts this is more than just a superficial code prettiness thing, it becomes very important to be able to tell if a method is local or not just by its name.

This sort of works but PowerShell complains every time I import that its not using a properly named verb. Is there a supported prefix for defining local functions/methods?

```
function _Get-Something {...}
function Get-SomethingElse { _Get-Something -arg sdfsdf .....}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-SomethingElse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example, I do not get the warning message (PowerShell 5.1) because you are not exporting the function `_Get-Something`.

If I do export it (`Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-SomethingElse, _Get-Something`), then the warning happens.

I'm not aware of any convention for this, but what I usually do is naming such a helper function within the module **without** a dash (`_Get-Something` --> `_GetSomething`) and use correct names with approved verbs for functions I do want to export. Then export the lazy way:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function *-*
```

It is also possible to 'hide' helper functions **inside** the exported function that uses it, like

```
function Get-SomethingElse { 
    # helper function inside
    function _Get-Something { Write-Host "Hi from $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)" }

    _Get-Something -arg 'sdfsdf .....'
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-SomethingElse
```

This too does not show the warning on my machine.

Lastly, you can get rid of the warning by adding the `-DisableNameChecking` switch to the command:

```
Import-Module 'D:\test.psm1' -DisableNameChecking
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didnt release you dont get errors if you dont export. I think I was exporting everything before so maybe that was why

Comment: @red888 Yes, I think you were doing that. Also note that when you leave out the `Export-ModuleMember` line completely, all functions and aliases are exported by default, only the variables are not. Perhaps that was the case.