# Can I hide a definition from Import-Module?

Tags: powershell, import, module

I have a file with a group of function definitions and variable assignments, some of which are only used to help other functions or definitions. Is it possible to hide these from the `Import-Module` command such that the user cannot see them?

Alternatively, is there a method for manually declaring exports?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conventions and native support for defining private functions inside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476716/conventions-and-native-support-for-defining-private-functions-inside-a-module)

Comment: If you don't export a function from the module, the user cannot see it. They can of course edit the module psm1 to find it if they have a mind to.

Comment: While this does indeed answer my question, this is only because the question asked there presupposes the answer to my question. The fact that `Export-ModuleMember` must manually be used was not known to me and is an answer to this question, but not that one.

Comment: @Scepticalist Now PowerShell tells me I can "only use that command in a module". Why is my `.ps1` file not a module?

Comment: OK, I get it. I need a `.psm1` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't been exporting your module members manually. Use the `Export-ModuleMember` Cmdlet to do so. If you do not export a member, it won't be seen by the user.

To export a function/cmdlet/alias/variable, write

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function MyFunction -Alias MyAlias -Cmdlet MyCmdlet -Variable MyVariable
```

at the bottom of your module file.